# getting warning and fatal error when trying to make a table through PHP

Tags: php, windows

So i have 3 files with code with the html code for my 2 input fields for a user from my phpmyadmin, the second file is code for the session so if the entry was true then the user will get correct entry and if it was wrong they'll get wrong entry, the third one is basically the file through which we connect to the database with my table code. I will provide all 3 files right now:
this is login.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> MYSQL </title>
        <script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <input id="login" placeholder="Login"><br>
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <button id="entry"> Login </button>
    <script>
    $("#entry").click(function(){

        $.post("check.php", {login: $("#login").val(), password: $("#pass").val()},
        function(result){
        $("#status").html(result);

    })
})
    </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

this is loggedin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
@$entry=$_SESSION['login'];

if($entry == true){
    echo "correct entry";
}
else{
    echo "wrong entry";
}

?>
```

and lastly adminpanel.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
@$entry=$_SESSION['login'];
if($entry == true){
    require "config/con.php";

    $sql="SELECT products.name, products.price, orders.qty, SUM(orders.price) FROM orders, products WHERE orders.product_id=products.id GROUP BY products.name";

    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    echo "<table border=1>";
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$line['name']."</td></td>".$line['price']."</td></td>".$line['qty']."</td></td>".$line['SUM(orders.price)']."</td></tr>";
        }   
        echo "</table>";    
} else{
    echo "wrong entry";
}

?>
```

here are the errors that i'm getting:

> Warning: require(C:\xampp1\htdocs\mysql7\config\con): failed to open
>   stream: Bad file descriptor in C:\xampp1\htdocs\mysql7\adminpanel.php
>   on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'config/con.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp1\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\mysql7\adminpanel.php on line 5

so my `config/con.php` is in my mysql7 folder with all of the other files. i've used it multiple times with other files it's worked fine.what's wrong with the connection?

Comment: Looks like con.php isn't where you're looking for it.

Comment: Rename your `con.php` to a more understandable `connection.php` and make sure that you know that `con` is a windows reserved command.

Comment: you mean the actual file name? then change it in notepad aswell?

Comment: Share directory structure of you project, so we can figure out where `con.php` lying.

Comment: sorry totally forgot about that, but how should i share it?

Answer (score -1):

yes con.php doesn't work , i think it is related to windows commands or smthg , rename it and everything is cool.

Comment: Answers like this are more appropriate as a comment, especially when other users have already commented the same thing two years ago.